# Expandable ListView Item with no Child

Tags: android-studio, expandablelistview

So i created an expandable listView, works just fine. The problem is when i try to click an item witch has no children occours an exception because the function getChildrenCount is null. How can i solve this guys ? I really wanted this single item to have no children.

Comment: I already sovled the problem of the null excepetion, creating an empty array. But now i have another problem, i have a public method for onChildClick, but i wanted to click on the item and start an activity, but there is no method for that, only for children, how can i do things, like start an activity only clicking on the item ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So actually the solver to this was really simple. I just had to use a setOnGroupListener on this case cause i wanted to show a new intent right after i click on the Group item, instead on the other items that i used setOnChildListener cause i wanted to expand the group to a few childs and then on the childs i wanted to do something.